# How to state incomplete Ph.D in CV (not defended yet)?

Tags: phd, cv, job

I have read few tags and i could not find appropriate answers. So, here i am writing again.

I have completed my Ph.D research work, and completed all the credits required and published a paper. but i have not yet defended. one of my project doesn't have sufficient results to published. other than this there are other complications with supervisor, personal issues. but i was recommend to Licentiate degree (need to rethink about Licentiate).

My question is how do i present in my CV that I have not defended or it may be a licentiate degree. Or should i state in cover letter reason for not completing in time? I am applying jobs that has masters degree as requirement. in academics, companies mainly as Research engineer, laboratory assistant etc.

could someone help with right words that has to be put in CV? Thank you

Comment: It might be helpful to specify which country you're located in as part of the question, since answers will vary depending on where you are. I'm also not familiar with the Licentiate Degree; I'm not sure if this is a common degree or if it's a location-specific term.

Comment: Is the OP asking how to formally write in a CV that they are [ABD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_but_dissertation)?

Comment: "Licentiate" sounds to me like the difference in China between 毕业证 and 学位证, one verifies that you have met the coursework and academic requirements for a PhD, one is that you have fulfilled all of the university obligations, including successfully defending your thesis. Is this what you mean?